# How can I change my character's appearance after starting Pokémon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokémon GO [released today](http://au.ign.com/articles/2016/07/06/pokemon-go-begins-worldwide-launch), and in my haste to get started and catch some 'mons, I rushed through the character setup screen, thinking I could customise it later. However, I can't see a way to do this:

From the Main (Map) screen, clicking on the Pokéball, I can access a few options, but none to do with character customisation:

[image: Pokeball Menu]

'Settings' exists but nothing in there either:

[image: Settings Menu]

- Clicking on my Avatar's head brings up my Stats screen, but nothing in there can be customised:

[image: Stats Screen 1] [image: Stats Screen 2]

I can spin the 3D avatar (can't click or long press), the Gold Pikachu coin takes you to a shop, and the Journal just lists events like "Pokemon Caught" or "Received Pokeballs".

The game is linked to my Google account. Restarting the App/Phone didn't give any options on game startup either.

How can I customise my character after the initial setup? Or am I locked in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of version 0.31.0 you can now change your avatar's appearance by navigating to the new menu in your profile and tapping the "customize" option.

[image: Menu]

Comment: The option is now called 'Style' and is [in a slightly different position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfQ07.jpg)

Answer (score 33):

<s>>At this time, it is not possible to change your avatar or your team.</s>

Cited from [here](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958268-How-do-I-change-my-avatar-or-team-)

Since version 0.31, you can re-customize the avatar from the Trainer profile screen (click the right bottom menu).

Comment: To add, there aren't many customization options for now anyway. Guess we have to wait for a feature update. :)